# How should I flag a question about general programming concepts

Tags: discussion, flags

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18104626) question on S.O. review, and I'm not sure how best to handle it. At first I was going to flag it as unclear, but it is clear what he's asking to me, he wants a counter example to show that the given hypothesis is false. But it's more of a general programming idea rather than a specific problem. I'm not sure how to flag it or where it would belong.

Comment: It's not even a programming problem.  It's a computer science problem.  That's different.  Too Broad would also be fine.  And of course don't forget to downvote as well.

Comment: That looks very much like it is a homework question. We really should have a 'homework' flag

Comment: I don't really have a problem with homework questions, provided they show a clear programming problem and what they've tried to do to fix it. I marked it as too broad, though according to the dupe question, maybe blatantly off topic would be better.